# feedback form in iOS app - allowed?

Tags: ios, app-store

Would anyone one know if Apple has restrictions on providing a user feedback/bug report form within an app? I've searched around but haven't found anything very clear. Might seem a dumb question but I don't want to waste time on it if it is not allowed.

Also, assuming it is allowed - I guess I would do it through a server-based php script, rather than trying to wire it up through the user's email. I am *not* trying to capture the user's email or anything like that - just feedback/bug responses.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed, and there's nothing to stop you doing it through email either - what is the difference between emailing a bug report using MFMailComposeViewController and emailing anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I believe companies like Uservoice and GetSatisfaction have mobile sdks for submitting feedback about apps.

Uservoice lets people submit anonymously, GetSatisfaction requires an account.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this however you would like, lots of apps support emailing feedback but if you prefer to put in the work you could also do custom fields and have it simply send the response back through your own server.